# "Extract" intervals from series in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

If I in Google Sheets have a series defined as

```
[29060, 29062, 29331, 29332, 29333, 29334, 29335, 29336, 29337, 29338, 29339, 29340, 29341, 
29342, 29372, 29373].
```

How do I make them line up in intervals like this?

```
|To    |From   |  
|29060 |29062  |  
|29331 |29342  |  
|29372 |29373  |
```

I can't find any good answers for this anywhere. Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

## Data/Formulas

A1:

```
29060, 29062, 29331, 29332, 29333, 29334, 29335, 29336, 29337, 29338, 29339, 29340, 29341, 
29342, 29372, 29373
```

B1: `=transpose(split(A1,","))`. Converts the input text is an a vertical array.
C1: `=FILTER(B1:B16,mod(ROW(B1:B16),2)<>0)`. Returns values in odd rows.
D1: `=FILTER(B1:B16,mod(ROW(B1:B16),2)=0)`. Returns values in even rows.
E1: `=ArrayFormula(FILTER(C1:C8,{TRUE();C2:C8<>D1:D7+1}))`. Returns values that start a range.
F1:  `=ArrayFormula(FILTER(D1:D8,{D1:D7+2<>D2:D8;TRUE()}))`. Returns values that end a range.

## Result

Note: A1 values are not shown for readability.

```
+----+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    | A |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |
+----+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |   | 29060 | 29060 | 29062 | 29060 | 29062 |
|  2 |   | 29062 | 29331 | 29332 | 29331 | 29342 |
|  3 |   | 29331 | 29333 | 29334 | 29372 | 29373 |
|  4 |   | 29332 | 29335 | 29336 |       |       |
|  5 |   | 29333 | 29337 | 29338 |       |       |
|  6 |   | 29334 | 29339 | 29340 |       |       |
|  7 |   | 29335 | 29341 | 29342 |       |       |
|  8 |   | 29336 | 29372 | 29373 |       |       |
|  9 |   | 29337 |       |       |       |       |
| 10 |   | 29338 |       |       |       |       |
| 11 |   | 29339 |       |       |       |       |
| 12 |   | 29340 |       |       |       |       |
| 13 |   | 29341 |       |       |       |       |
| 14 |   | 29342 |       |       |       |       |
| 15 |   | 29372 |       |       |       |       |
| 16 |   | 29373 |       |       |       |       |
+----+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```